# How to freeze the first column when exporting to excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to freeze the first column within a worksheet within excel.

I am aware of how to freeze both horizontally and vertically using

```
c = ws['C3']
ws.freeze_panes = c
```

however, I am specifically looking for a way to only freeze column A

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.freeze_panes = 'B1'  # this will freeze the first column
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

So if you open an Excel spreadsheet and manually want to freeze the first column, the way you do it (other than selecting "Freeze First Column") is you would highlight column B and then go to **View** --> **Freeze Panes** --> **Freeze Panes**. This in turn freezes the first column or column A.

So you want to do the same thing as described above, so in the code use`sheet.freeze_panes = 'B1'`. This selects column B and then performs Freeze Pane on the selection.